# YouTube Embed Player Controls not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to hide the logo and title on the YouTube embed player. I'm taking a URL from a database and not directly writing it in code. I'm also using a datalist to show the results. Can someone tell me what I should do? I googled for a solution but most suggestions is for hiding the logo and title when YouTube video url is directly written in code.

Here's what I tried:

## 1

```
<object width="200" height="200">
    <param name="movie" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>'></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>' 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" 
        allowfullscreen="true" width="260" height="232">
    </embed>
</object>
```

## 2

```
<iframe width="260" height="230" src="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the various combinations of YouTube embedded [player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) using this [live demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo).

Based on what you describe, `modestbranding=1` will probably give you what you want.

You need to add in the player parameters to the end of your iframe `src` using standard URL parameter syntax, which in your example is stored in `#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url")`.